# Use WCF service as component with existing app.config

Tags: wcf, configuration

We have developed a WCF Service that will be used from another service.  Both of these are on the same machine, but we have to host them in IIS.  This restricts us to HTTP, which is kinda killing our performance.

Is there any way to use the other service as a component (thus reference the dll's), but still use the same (or perhaps a copy of) the configuration file.  Reducing the friction in case a move to 2K8 is made?

Thanks